# How do you append to an already existing string?

Tags: string, bash, shell, string-concatenation

I want append to a string so that every time I loop over it, it will add "test" to the string.

Like in `PHP` you would do:

```
$teststr = "test1\n"
$teststr .= "test2\n"
echo = "$teststr"
```

Returns:

```
test1
test2
```

But I need to do this in a shell script

Answer (score 269, accepted):

In classic sh, you have to do something like:

```
s=test1
s="${s}test2"
```

(there are lots of variations on that theme, like `s="$s""test2"`)

In bash, you can use +=:

```
s=test1
s+=test2
```

Answer (score 34):

```
$ string="test"
$ string="${string}test2"
$ echo $string
testtest2
```

Answer (score 16):

```
teststr=$'test1\n'
teststr+=$'test2\n'
echo "$teststr"
```

Answer (score 16):

```
#!/bin/bash
message="some text"
message="$message add some more"

echo $message
```

some text add some more

Answer (score 3):

```
VAR=$VAR"$VARTOADD(STRING)"   
echo $VAR
```

Answer (score 2):

thank-you Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams

i adapted slightly for better ease of use :)

placed at top of script

```
NEW_LINE=$'\n'
```

then to use easily with other variables

```
variable1="test1"
variable2="test2"

DESCRIPTION="$variable1$NEW_LINE$variable2$NEW_LINE"
```

OR
to append thank-you William Pursell

```
DESCRIPTION="$variable1$NEW_LINE"
DESCRIPTION+="$variable2$NEW_LINE"

echo "$DESCRIPTION"
```

Comment: Why not just do `DESCRIPTION="${variable1}\n${variable2}\n"` ? Seems like a cleaner way to achieve the same thing, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: there is a difference, ive just tested it. with that method i need -e if im to echo it, with what i suggested you don't. so theirs deffo a difference!

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

msg1=${1} #First Parameter
msg2=${2} #Second Parameter

concatString=$msg1"$msg2" #Concatenated String
concatString2="$msg1$msg2"

echo $concatString 
echo $concatString2
```