# How to use function argument as a part of a string in ZSH?

Tags: function, arguments, zsh

I have ZSH function with arguments test() { echo **$1ext**; } calling like: test arg

This does not work if $1 in a function is part of a string as $1ext (works for $1-ext or $1.ext).
Is there a way to use like that: $1ext?
(In the not-proper exapmle of echo, I could use && but this is not really echo but arguments of a larger fucntion.)

Comment: Solution is to append ext to argument:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250131/how-do-you-append-to-an-already-existing-string

Comment: `printf "%sext\n" "$1"` or maybe `print -r -- "${1}ext"`

Comment: What error are you seeing? `zsh` documents `$1ext` as being equivalent to `${1}ext`

Comment: @chepner That is exactly how I soved it per link I wrote. Point is that it was not obvious to me in the beginning, as I never had to use it before. Thanks.

Comment: I can not reproduce the behaviour: Doing a `foo() { echo $1ext }; foo foo` correctly outputs `fooext`. This is using zsh version 5.8.1. What do you get when you do a `echo $ZSH_VERSION`?

Comment: Don't name your functions like existing shell builtins! Sooner or later this will bite you.

Comment: @user1934428 Really so, `$1ext` was not a proper example, better one is `$101` i.e. appending numbers to argument. As written here, solution is `${1}01`.

Comment: Well, this is obvious, because zsh treats `$101` as parameter numer 101. In the same way, `$abc` is expanding the parameter named `abc`, while `${ab}c` would expand the parameter `ab`, and add the letter `c` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to append ext to argument: [How do you append to an already existing string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250131/how-do-you-append-to-an-already-existing-string)

zsh treats $101 as parameter numer 101. In the same way, $abc is expanding the parameter named abc, while ${ab}c would expand the parameter ab, and add the letter c to it.

Note: I added an answer before, but it somehow was changed to my 1st comment. Thanks to those who also commented.